# mySQL convert a character in a string to upper case

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to databases and need a little help with converting characters to uppercase, I can either change the whole string to uppercase or the first letter, however the problem arises when I need to convert a letter that is contained within a string.  For example if the surname of an individual in Mcdonald, I need to change this to McDonald or if they have a jnr or snr after their name this needs to be changed to Jnr or Snr. Any guidance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Also, please edit your question with one of your attempts at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: This should be done *once* by whoever enters the data.

Comment: This is more of naming rules that you have to consider in your business logic and it is not a database related question.

Comment: My attempt at this was as follows: UPDATE items SET lastname = WHEN lastname LIKE 'MC%' THEN CONCAT('Mc', SUBSTRING_INDEX(lastname, 'Mc',-1)).  Is this even along the right lines??

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use the REPLACE() function.  Something like,

```
UPDATE items SET lastname = REPLACE(lastname, 'MC', 'Mc\' ' );
```

For "MCDonalds" input, this will return "Mc' Donalds".

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c1da/2